# How can this XML file be read by JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I can already read and write XML using JAXB in my unittest but when I try to process an actual file

I get this error: `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"resources"). Expected elements are <{}item>,<{}plurals>,<{tools:http://schemas.android.com/tools}resources>,<{}string>`

The file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="de">

    <string name="name1" translatable="false">value 1</string>
    <string name="name2" translatable="false">value 2</string>
</resources>
```

What the unittest is able to write (and also read is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:resources xmlns:ns2="tools:http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <string name="name1" translatable="false">value1</string>
    <string name="name2" translatable="true">value2</string>
    <plurals>
        <item quantity="one">%d one</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d more</item>
    </plurals>
</ns2:resources>
```

It seems that `xmlns:tools` could cause the issue that's different to `ns2:resources` which is created for some reason.

The top level container element is annotated as:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="resources", namespace = "tools:http://schemas.android.com/tools")
```

The XmlRootElement doesn't have further options to set how could I replace the namespace "ns2" by "tools"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `@XmlRootElement` annotation is telling JAXB that the root element corresponding to your class is composed of the name `resources` and the namespace `http://schemas.android.com/tools` below is the corrected annodation.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="resources", namespace = "http://schemas.android.com/tools")
```

Your XML document needs to ensure that the prefix associated with the `http://schemas.android.com/tools` namespace is used to prefix the `resources` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tools:resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:locale="de">

    <string name="name1" translatable="false">value 1</string>
    <string name="name2" translatable="false">value 2</string>
</tools:resources>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:resources xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <string name="name1" translatable="false">value1</string>
    <string name="name2" translatable="true">value2</string>
    <plurals>
        <item quantity="one">%d one</item>
        <item quantity="other">%d more</item>
    </plurals>
</ns2:resources>
```

---

### UPDATE #1

> Thanks for your response, the test doc is created programatically with
>   ns2 as namespace can be read from the code, the problem is that I
>   can't parse this format.

With the corrected `@XmlRootElement` information it doesn't matter what the prefix used is.

### UPDATE #2

If the root element in your XML document is not namespace qualified then then `@XmlRootElement` annotation should not contain namespace information.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="resources")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the test doc is created programatically with ns2 as namespace can be read from the code, the problem is that I can't parse this format.

Comment: @stacker - I have updated my answer with some information that should help.

Comment: I get a quit large input file and cannot parse it (first xml snippet) I already tried to fix the namespace attribute in the @XmlRootElement annotation no success. I only included the format that the code is able to write and read as this might help exclude some potential issues.

Comment: @stacker - See Update #2